# How to convert char[] to string?

Tags: java, string, char, type-conversion

I have a question in this case how to convert char[] to string?(Must explicitly convert the char[] to a String) sorry being a novice programmer i am asking this.

```
 String str3 = "Dad saw I was Playing";
        System.out.println(str3.toCharArray() + "\n" + str3.toLowerCase() );
        System.out.println(str3.toCharArray());
```

Output:
[C@1034bb5 //this is what I am getting for first str3.tochararray(),how to resolve this?
dad saw i was playing
Dad saw I was Playing

Comment: Why are you calling `toCharArray()` method in the first place?

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: @noelob
Dad saw I was Playing:   I am expecting this answer as i got it on second str3.tocharArray()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.toString(char[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-char:A-) (or create your own method if you prefer a different formatting). Something like,

```
String str3 = "Dad saw I was Playing";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str3.toCharArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(str3.toCharArray() + "\n" + str3.toLowerCase() );`

This first calls toString over CharArray which outputs [C@1034bb5 and then append it to the rest of the string and print.

`System.out.println(str3.toCharArray());` -- This calls the overridden method in PrintStream class which can interpret char array and print it.

You can explicitly convert your char array to string and print.